# Printing the list of files from FTP?

Tags: groovy, filemaker

I'm trying to  read the list of files from FTP server and printing all files as output.
please check the below code once.

```
    start()
    def start(){
    def store;
      def ftpClient = new FTPClient()
      ftpClient.connect(server)
      println(ftpClient.replyString)
      ftpClient.login(user,pass)
      ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
      def fileslist = ftpClient.listFiles("/");
      return fileslist;
      ftpClient.disconnect()
    }
```

### output:

```
        04-03-18  05:20PM                    4 Autoplus.txt
        04-03-18  08:13PM                   19 Autoplus6.txt
        03-30-18  06:36PM       <DIR>          sample
```

### Required output format

```
        |Autoplus.txt|{Tue Apr 03 17:20:00 IST 2018}|
        |Autoplus6.txt|{Tue Apr 03 18:13:00 IST 2018}|
```

How can I print the files in the required out format.

If anybody having idea please let me know

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: What this has to do with FileMaker?

Comment: @Nicolai thanks for giving response .This will connect to FTP server and returns the list of files from server.But i need to print the values as required.

Comment: You can manipulate strings in PHP or FileMaker to get the result you need. This would be even easier if it is guaranteed that the file names will not have spaces. Plus you will need to convert the timestamp into a different format.